# Returning a filtered nested array inside an array of objects in React

Tags: arrays, reactjs, filter, use-state

I have a piece of data in a 'serviceProviders' state which holds data as so:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Mental Wellness",
    "services": [
      {
        "name": "Footcare & more",
        "serviceType": "Footcare",
        "location": {
          "lat": 43.65040363335024,
          "lng": -79.38396226829892
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "Brain Wellnes",
        "serviceType": "Mental",
        "location": {
          "lat": 43.655931348619475,
          "lng": -79.37928150811159
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "Physical service",
        "serviceType": "Physical",
        "location": {
          "lat": 43.70312522921196,
          "lng": -79.34393786935266
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I want to write a function which filters the nested array(services) based on matching serviceType to some other variable and returns the whole object with the updated services array and sets a new state.

something along these lines:

```
  const filter = () => {
    serviceProviders.map((provider) => {
      const filtered = provider.services.filter((service) => service.serviceType === 'Mental')
      setServiceProviders(serviceProviders => [...serviceProviders, serviceProviders.services = filtered ])
    })
  }
```

should return:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Mental Wellness",
    "services": [
      {
        "name": "Brain Wellnes",
        "serviceType": "Mental",
        "location": {
          "lat": 43.655931348619475,
          "lng": -79.37928150811159
       }
    ]
  }
]
```

any help would be much appreciated. thank you.

Comment: I don't understand what is unclear? Users will have an array of serviceTypePreferences that will be tested against the serviceTypes and look for matches. regardless, the functionality won't change

Comment: Say there are multiple top-level providers and some of them don't have any matching services... what happens to those top-level objects in the result

Comment: There can always be checks for that. I can't even get to that if I can't get the query to work. this is also why i wanted a piece of state that holds everything, and a piece of state that holds the filtered results if any.

Comment: I'm just asking what should happen? There's really only two options; filter out those top-level objects entirely **or** include them with empty `services` arrays

Comment: so preferably if there are no matches then return the original services array

Comment: See what I mean about your question being unclear? Do you think you could update it with a better example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I'd suggest using the [useMemo](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo) hook to create transformed sets so you don't mutate your original data.

To filter down the services to ones with the selected `serviceType` *or* as per your comment...

> if there are no matches then return the original services array

try this...

```js
const [ serviceProviders, setServiceProviders ] = useState([
  // your array data here
])
const [ serviceType, setServiceType ] = useState("Mental")

const providers = useMemo(() => {
  const predicate = svc => svc.serviceType === serviceType

  return serviceProviders.map(sp => ({
    ...sp,
    services: sp.services.some(predicate) // are there matches
      ? sp.services.filter(predicate) // yes, use the filtered array
      : [...sp.services] // no, clone the original array
  }))
}, [ serviceProviders, serviceType ]) // dependencies
```

This memoized value will only recompute if either of the dependencies change.

---

If you wanted to completely filter out top-level objects with no matches, try this instead

```js
return serviceProviders.filter(sp => sp.services.some(predicate))
  .map(sp => ({
    ...sp,
    services: sp.services.filter(predicate)
  }))
```

Comment: amazing solution. How would you go about setting the return into a new piece of state as opposed to the useMemo. Assuming the serviceType(s) can dynamically change based on user preferences and the query needs to happen again and state needs to update. My syntax was very similar to yours but when I tried to set it into a new piece of state of code was failing. Thanks!

Comment: You shouldn't need it as state if it's only ever derived from existing state. That's exactly what `useMemo` is for; any time your state changes, the memo will re-compute

Comment: gotcha! thanks a bunch!